# Question on distributing weight

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

My question is about distributing a set of non-negative weights over a set of n items, in a way that sum of weights equals 1.
For example if n=2, then w1 can be some p (where p is the probability of item1, say 1/N, where N is the number of items in society where item1 comes from); and w2 is then 1-p.
The question is how to advise a formula (any), when there are for example 3 or 5 items instead of 2?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example, 3 items, then the probability for the items are $p_1,p_2$ and $p_3$. $p_1$ can be expressed as $p_1=1-p_2-p_3$. This condition and the condition $0 < p_i < 1 \ \forall \ i=1,2,3 $ have to be fullfilled.

If you have a uniform distribution $p_i=\frac{1}{n} \forall i=1,2,3,...,n$

Comment: Thanks, my main prob is: I have a 3*300 matrix of items,M,in which in every column (3items) I have to distribute weight as I mentioned before, but weights can't be all the same for all columns. 

In case there are only 2 items in a column (2*300 matrix), a solution could be this:
if i=indicator of column then 
w of M[1][i]=i*1/300 
and 
w of M[2][i]=1-i*1/300. 

It is designed this way, so that the weight values are not the same in all columns (even or uniform distribution of weights over matrix as it is called).

I do not know how I can design weights in a similar way for 3 items in a column.

Comment: @Seddie Suppose you want to generate at random 3 values with the sum of 1. You can use Excel or a similar program. The cells are a1, b1, c1 for the first column. The formula for a1 is then $: \\ \color{blue}{\text{=randbetween(0,100)/100}}$. For b1 $: \color{blue}{\text{=randbetween(0,100-a1*100)}/100}$. And for c1: $\color{blue}{\text{=1-a1-b1}}$ You will get random values with two decimal after the decimal point.

Comment: @Seddie Alternatively you can use $\color{blue}{\text{=round(rand(),d)}}$ to generate a random variable, between 0 and 1, with a number of $\color{blue}{d}$ decimals after the decimal toint.

Comment: Thanks calculus; I think this works perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: Actually my struggle was to find some mathematical basis of distribution, that produces all ai,bi,ci values; However, my own conclusion also was solving the problem using random number generation, which sure will work perfectly for my problem. So, thanks for the time and comments.